# dask equivalent of df.loc[df.index.intesection(mylabels)]

Tags: dask

When I run `df.loc[mylabels]` in dask I get a warning with the link to

> > Warning Starting in 0.21.0, using .loc or [] with a list with one or more missing labels, is deprecated, in favor of .reindex [*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-with-list-with-missing-labels-is-deprecated)

This page also says:

> > Alternatively, if you want to select only valid keys, the following is idiomatic and efficient; it is guaranteed to preserve the dtype of the selection.

```
In [106]: labels = [1, 2, 3]
In [107]: s.loc[s.index.intersection(labels)]
Out[107]: 
1    2
2    3
dtype: int64
```

Dask indexes do not have an `intersection` method.
So hat is the recommended way to achieve the above effect in dask?

The problem with `df.loc[mylabels]` is that `mylabels` contains items not in df.index.

Answer (score 1):

For now it looks like you should continue calling `df.loc[labels]`.

It looks like things have changed upstream and probably dask.dataframe needs to follow a bit.  I recommend submitting a bug report to https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/new

Comment: It turns out that `df.loc[mylabels]` already throws exceptions when when some of the labels are not in the index.